# Amount of time and 間

Tags: grammar, time

When expressing "It takes about 1 hour and 15 minutes", would it be best to say

```
１時間１５分掛かる。
```

or

```
１時１５分掛かる。
```

or maybe

```
１時１５分間掛かる。
```

?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

１時 means "one o'clock". １時間 means "one hour". So you have to say １時間１５分掛かる。 If you want to express the "about", you can say およそ１時間１５分掛かる。　or １時間１５分くらい掛かる。